# How do i get this program to just produce as output: 265 for the variable?

Tags: python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# i2c_ADXL345.py  este es el accelerómetro de 3 ejes
# 2015-04-01
# Public Domain

import time
import struct
import sys

import pigpio # http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html

if sys.version > '3':
   buffer = memoryview

BUS=0

ADXL345_I2C_ADDR=0x53

#RUNTIME=60.0 This is the original line.
#RUNTIME=0.10 / This was the new line

pi=pigpio.pi() # open local Pi

h = pi.i2c_open(BUS, ADXL345_I2C_ADDR)

if h >= 0: # Connected OK?

   # Initialise ADXL345.
   pi.i2c_write_byte_data(h, 0x2d, 0)  # POWER_CTL reset.
   pi.i2c_write_byte_data(h, 0x2d, 8)  # POWER_CTL measure.
   pi.i2c_write_byte_data(h, 0x31, 0)  # DATA_FORMAT reset.
   pi.i2c_write_byte_data(h, 0x31, 11) # DATA_FORMAT full res +/- 16g.

   read = 0

#   start_time = time.time() ?part of the RUNTIME?

#   while (time.time()-start_time) < RUNTIME: ?part of the RUNTIME?

      # 0x32 = X LSB, 0x33 = X MSB
      # 0x34 = Y LSB, 0x35 = Y MSB
      # 0x36 = Z LSB, 0x37 = Z MSB

      # < = little endian

(s, b) = pi.i2c_read_i2c_block_data(h, 0x32, 6)

if s >= 0:
         (x, y, z) = struct.unpack('<3h', buffer(b))
         print("{} {} {}".format(x, y, z))
         read += 1

pi.i2c_close(h)

pi.stop()

print()
```

The above code produces

265 -17 -34

as output.  My question is how do i change the code so that only the "256" is produced? What is the name of the variable which contains this value?  These seem to be pretty basic questions, but since i'm not a programmer i'm trying to take this one step at a time.  i'm trying to "adapt" this code so that i can substitute it into Jay Dosher's code for Sun location, but since he's using a different IMU Joan, from Raspberry Pi, kindly made up the above code to read our IMU.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

# i2c_ADXL345.py  this is the 3 axis accelerometer
# 2015-04-01
# Public Domain
# Note - Don't forget to run pigpiod first

import time
import struct
import sys

import pigpio # http://abyz.co.uk/rpi/pigpio/python.html

if sys.version > '3':
   buffer = memoryview

BUS=0

ADXL345_I2C_ADDR=0x53

#RUNTIME=60.0 This is the original line.
#RUNTIME=0.10 / This was the new line

pi=pigpio.pi() # open local Pi

h = pi.i2c_open(BUS, ADXL345_I2C_ADDR)

if h >= 0: # Connected OK?

   # Initialise ADXL345.
   pi.i2c_write_byte_data(h, 0x2d, 0)  # POWER_CTL reset.
   pi.i2c_write_byte_data(h, 0x2d, 8)  # POWER_CTL measure.
   pi.i2c_write_byte_data(h, 0x31, 0)  # DATA_FORMAT reset.
   pi.i2c_write_byte_data(h, 0x31, 11) # DATA_FORMAT full res +/- 16g.

   read = 0

#   start_time = time.time() ?part of the RUNTIME?

#   while (time.time()-start_time) < RUNTIME: ?part of the RUNTIME?

      # 0x32 = X LSB, 0x33 = X MSB
      # 0x34 = Y LSB, 0x35 = Y MSB
      # 0x36 = Z LSB, 0x37 = Z MSB

      # < = little endian

(s, b) = pi.i2c_read_i2c_block_data(h, 0x32, 6)

if s >= 0:
         (x, y, z) = struct.unpack('<3h', buffer(b))
#         (x) = struct.unpack('<3h', buffer(b)) # Let's experiment again.
#         print("{} {} {}".format(x, y, z))
         print("{}".format(x))

         read += 1

pi.i2c_close(h)

pi.stop()

print()
```

This is the new code which now only produces 254.  Our remaining question is: What is the name of the variable which has this value?

Comment: I've never written a single line of python code, but `print("{} {} {}".format(x, y, z))` looks suspicious. I would try changing it to `print("{}".format(x))` to see what happens.

Comment: That's what i tried!  i checked the script and that was the last line i had changed.  It produces (264, -14, -33).  Not only does it produce the three axis, but it now encloses them in parathesis - lol.

Comment: Oho!  i just returned this line (x, y, z) = struct.unpack('<3h', buffer(b)) to its uncommented out (#) state and now the script only produces the 264!  So, the only remaining question is - What is the name of the variable which has this value?

Comment: That type of change does seem to work. See http://ideone.com/2ArNUz. `x` has the first of those three values. Yes, commenting out the assignment of the variable but then using it is not likely to be what you intend.

Comment: Thanks, mah - your humor was also appreciated.  The code example was excellent - short and to the point - wish i had found it earlier.  Have a wonderful day!  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the variable in this case is `x`, as defined in `(x, y, z) = struct.unpack('<3h', buffer(b))`.